# feature comparision between glassfish 3.1 and 4.0

Tags: glassfish

I am new to glassfish. When I add Glassfish server in Eclipse Juno, I have to choose between Glassfish 3.1 and 4.0 server, which is better supported? which specific features do they have?

This is what I saw in glassfish [doc](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/PlanForGlassFish4.0):

> GlassFish 4.0 is intended to be the next major release in Project
>   GlassFish. This release will implement the Java EE 7 specifications,
>   contribute to the Java EE 7 Reference Implementation and Development
>   Kit. The release is being designed with primary focus on the following
>   features :
>
> - Higher Productivity
> - HTML5 Support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GlassFish 3.x supports Java EE 6. GlassFish 4.0 will support Java EE 7. A vast majority of new features in GlassFish 4.0 are actually Java EE 7 features. To find out what's new in Java EE 7, [register for next week's Java EE 7 Live Launch Event](https://glassfishplugins.java.net/) and you can learn what's new.

GlassFish 4.0 is nearly final. Wait a few days (literally only a few more days) and you'll be able to download the final release of GlassFish 4.0.

IMHO, just use GlassFish 4.0. FYI, the [early builds of Eclipse Keplar](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php?release=kepler) already have support for Java EE 7 projects and GlassFish 4.0. The Juno GlassFish plugin will also be updated to support GlassFish 4.0. We'll also update the [GlassFIsh IDE Plugins page](https://glassfishplugins.java.net/) next week with more information.

Answer (score 1):

**Glassfish 3.1** - Java EE 6 compliant server.

**Glassfish 4.0** - Java EE 7 compliant server.